# Can't figure what's causing Unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I'm getting this error in console

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '(' ... line 49
```

This is problematic line:

```
 trackEnded: function() {
```

and This is Whole code, I just don't see why am I getting that error?

```
// Initialize audio js
      $(document).ready(function($) {


              // Setup the player to autoplay the next track
              trackEnded: function() {
                  var next = $('.main article.playing').next();
                  if (!next.length) next = $('.main article').first();
                  next.addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
                  audio.load($('.article-play', next).attr('data-src'));
                  audio.play();
                  $('.article-play', next).removeAttr('data-playa').attr("data-pausea", '5');
                  var nextPlay = $('.article-play', next);
                  $('.article-play').not(nextPlay).removeAttr('data-pausea').attr("data-playa", '4');
              }


          //Synchronize Main player with articles
          $(".audiojs .play-pause").click(function() {
              var element = $('.playing .article-play')
              var play = element.attr('data-playa')
              var pause = element.attr('data-pausea')
              if (play == '4') {
                  element.removeAttr('data-playa').attr("data-pausea", '5');
              } else if (pause == '5') {
                  element.removeAttr('data-pausea').attr("data-playa", '4');
              }
          })

          // Load in a track on click
          $('.article-play').click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              if ($(this).closest('article').hasClass('playing')) {
                  var play = $(this).attr('data-playa')
                  var pause = $(this).attr('data-pausea')
                  if (play == '4') {
                      $(this).removeAttr('data-playa').attr("data-pausea", '5');
                      $('.article-play').not($(this)).removeAttr('data-pausea').attr("data-playa", '4');
                      audio.play();
                  } else if (pause == '5') {
                      $(this).removeAttr('data-pausea').attr("data-playa", '4');
                      audio.pause();
                  }
              } else {
                  $(this).closest('article').addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
                  audio.load($(this).attr('data-src'));
                  audio.play();
                  $(this).removeAttr('data-playa').attr("data-pausea", '5');
                  $('.article-play').not($(this)).removeAttr('data-pausea').attr("data-playa", '4');
              }
          });

          // Keyboard shortcuts
          $(document).keydown(function(e) {
              var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
              // right arrow
              if (unicode == 39) {
                  var next = $('.main article.playing').next();
                  if (!next.length) next = $('.main article').first();
                  next.find('.article-play').click();
                  // back arrow
              } else if (unicode == 37) {
                  var prev = $('.main article.playing').prev();
                  if (!prev.length) prev = $('.main article').last();
                  prev.find('.article-play').click();
                  // spacebar
              } else if (unicode == 32 && document.activeElement.nodeName !== 'INPUT') {
                  audio.playPause();
                  var element = $('.playing .article-play')
                  var play = element.attr('data-playa')
                  var pause = element.attr('data-pausea')
                  if (play == '4') {
                      element.removeAttr('data-playa').attr("data-pausea", '5');
                  } else if (pause == '5') {
                      element.removeAttr('data-pausea').attr("data-playa", '4');
                  }
              }
          });
      });
```

Comment: why are you using $ inside function paramere in below line $(document).ready(function($) {

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar - He probably meant `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    // Setup the player to autoplay the next track
    trackEnded: function() {
        ...
    }
    ...
)};
```

is incorrect syntax

You are probably looking to do:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    // Setup the player to autoplay the next track
    function trackEnded() {
        ...
    }
    ...
)};
```

Also, looking at your tabulation, and comments, it seems that your intended code was something like:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    // Setup the player to autoplay the next track
    $(element).AudioPlugin({
        trackEnded: function() {
            ...
        }
    });
    ...
)};
```

The difference is that, for an assumed AudioPlugin, I am passing an initialisation/options object which defines a function callback on `trackEnded`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to write object synax inside function scope and this is incorrect syntax.

Should be:

```
function trackEnded() {
    // rest or your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplification of your code that still reproduces the issue:

```
function(){
    trackEnded: false
}
```

To sum up: you're attempting to define an object key but you don't have an object literal.